# CSS update working for 'npm run start', but not 'npm run build'

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

My code is simply trying to rotate a hamburger menu on open.

I have JS that toggles the `open` class on button click. This works fine running `npm run start` (`NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --mode development`), but this particular CSS (SCSS) code doesn't get compiled on `npm run build` (`NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production`).

I am using SCSS, Tailwind and vanilla JS. I have added other SCSS in the same file and tested the JS which also works just fine. The CSS seems valid to me.

What can I do to debug this issue?

**CSS**

```css
.open .hamburger__top-bun {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger__bottom-bun {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<button data-behaviour="navToggle" id="menuBtn" class="z-100 hamburger flex justify-center items-center lg:hidden focus:outline-none" type="button">
  <span class="hamburger__top-bun"></span>
  <span class="hamburger__bottom-bun"></span>
</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
const navToggle = document.querySelector('[data-behaviour="navToggle"]')

navToggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const btn = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
    const nav = document.getElementById('mobile-menu');

    btn.classList.toggle('open');
    nav.classList.toggle('flex');
    nav.classList.toggle('hidden');
    console.log(btn);
});
```

Comment: Have you installed and configured `scss-loader` in webpack ?

Comment: Could you create a runnable [mcve] reproducing the bug? Create a codesandbox using the exact output of the `npm run build` command (the contents of `./dist` folder). Then we'll be able to inspect it and tell you what's wrong with it.